# Do searches in RichText Field?

Tags: python, django, ckeditor, richtext

I am using ckeditor for manage rich text. I need to do searches in this field, but for example, words with strange characters are saved with html format. Example, in my front page this is the word 'està' in BD is save as 'est&agrave', them, the search never will match.

Some advice?, I am thinking in use html2text functionality to transform html-text in plain text.

Thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to save your content in unicode instead of using the HTML entities, set this to your config

```
config.removePlugins = 'entities';
config.entities = false;
```

I do this because I need 100% XML compatability and so far it works well enough, but I also remove certain XML-breaking characters that clever users paste into the editor.